# Can't find my error of " invalid attempt to read when no data is present when submit"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I need help as I had create the registration page for the users and everything goes smooth until they encounter the error of

> "Invalid Attempt to read when no data is presented"

whenever submit.

I keep on track the bugs and fix it and still not able fix as encounter another error like "connection needed to close" or etc. Below are my original code and need help:

---

```
  protected void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {



        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);


        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        String email = TextBox3.Text.Trim();
        String select = ("select Email from Customer where email=@Email");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandText = select;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);


        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('ERROR!!! Email Exists')", true);
            return;
        }


        else
        {

            String FullName;
            String FirstName;
            String LastName;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Type"].Value = this.DropDownList2.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("NatureBusiness", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["NatureBusiness"].Value = this.DropDownList5.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Title"].Value = this.DropDownList1.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["FirstName"].Value = this.TextBox1.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["LastName"].Value = this.TextBox2.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Fullname", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Fullname"].Value = this.TextBox1.Text + " " + this.TextBox2.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Ac_Manager", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Ac_Manager"].Value = this.DropDownList3.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Remarks", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Remarks"].Value = this.TextBox13.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("City", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["City"].Value = this.TextBox12.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Country"].Value = this.DropDownList4.Text;



            cmd.Parameters.Add("Job_Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Job_Title"].Value = this.TextBox4.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Company", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Company"].Value = this.TextBox5.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Mobile_Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Mobile_Phone"].Value = this.TextBox8.Text + this.TextBox6.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("ForeignNoF", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["ForeignNoF"].Value = this.TextBox14.Text + this.TextBox15.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("ForeignNoT", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["ForeignNoT"].Value = this.TextBox16.Text + this.TextBox17.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Office_Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Office_Phone"].Value = this.TextBox9.Text + this.TextBox7.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Staff", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Staff"].Value = this.Label1.Text;


            FirstName = TextBox1.Text;
            LastName = TextBox2.Text;
            FullName = TextBox1.Text + " " + TextBox2.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Customer] ([Type], [NatureBusiness], [Title], [Firstname], [Lastname], [Fullname], [Company], [Mobile_Phone], [Office_Phone], [ForeignNoF], [ForeignNoT], [Email], [Job_Title], [City], [Country], [Ac_Manager], [Remarks], [Staff]) VALUES (@Type, @NatureBusiness, @Title, @Firstname, @Lastname, @Fullname, @Company, @Mobile_Phone, @Office_Phone, @ForeignNoF, @ForeignNoT, @Email, @Job_Title, @City, @Country, @Ac_Manager, @Remarks, @Staff)";




            try 
            {



                conn.Open();


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Record Saved Successfully.');window.location='DatabaseEntry.aspx';", true);



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

               Response.Write("Oops!! Following error occured: " + ex.Message.ToString());


            }
            finally
            {

                conn.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();

            }


        }
  }
```

---

Error Appeared:

> Server Error in "/" Application.
>
> Stack Trace: [InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when
>   no data is present.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataisReady(Int32
>   columnIndex, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColum, Boolean PermitAsync,
>   string methodName) +6531242
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean
>   setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn) +81
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i) +43
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i) +151
>
> vnetwork.Account.DatabaseEntry.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   +432
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestmain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178
>
> Remarks: User told me some times is leave it open the page awhile then
>   whenever try to key in and submit and error above shown and also
>   sometimes trying to key in 2nd time data.

Comment: Where does the error occur? Post the full exception including the call stack. That' easy to do by calling `ex.ToString()`. This error is typically related to DataReaders and your code doesn't seem to use any

Comment: Hi, the error display as ""Invalid Attempt to read when no data is present" whenever submit the second data.
First entry is no problem, but error appear when submit second entry.

Comment: What line? The exception message already includes that. Also post the *full* message including the call stack. It doesn't help at all talking about first and second post in a 50+ line snippet.

Comment: i just edited at above question, still user having the error

Comment: Did you notice that the error occurs in a *different* method? The error occurs in the `Page_Load` method of your DatabaseEntry class. Did you try debugging your code or did you simply assume it was the button's event handler? If you had tried debugging, the debugger would have stopped at the point the exception occured. Please replace what you posted here with the *relevant* code